# View controller problems with old navigation bar and tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a view controller which was attached to a navigation controller at one point in time.  it is still showing some ghost of the navigation bar?  It is also showing the Tab Bar but there is not tab bar item shown on it?

any ideas how to fix this, or is it a delete and remake?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its either the alpha of the rootVC or you have. tab bar controller on the second one. Check your identity inspector on both views